# Create a 2 part primary key where the 2nd part auto increments and resets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a 2 part primary key on a details table in SQL server the 1st part is an FK to the master table called Audit_Header it has a primary key of AuditID INT Identity(1,1)

The Audit_Detail table will have a composite primary key of AuditID and SeqNo Where AuditID is the link to Audit_Header.

I want the SeqNo filed to increment but for each AuditID only. So if I have the following situation:

```
Audit_Header.AuditID: 12345
       Audit_DetailAuditID: 12345
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 1
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 2
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 3
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 4

Audit_Header.AuditID: 12333
       Audit_DetailAuditID: 12333
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 1
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 2
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 3
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 4
```

Not:

```
Audit_Header.AuditID: 12345
       Audit_DetailAuditID: 12345
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 1
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 2
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 3
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 4

Audit_Header.AuditID: 12333
       Audit_DetailAuditID: 12333
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 5
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 6
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 7
       Audit_Detail.SEQNO: 8
```

I can't figure out for the life of me how to set that up in SQL Server.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you ever delete individual rows for a given `AuditID`? If you delete `12333 / 3` do you want `12333 / 4` to stay intact or should that row then become `12333 / 3`? Isn't there something else about a sequential row that can uniquely identify it?

Comment: No, there's not going to be any deletion of the child records. I'll have a flag to tell me if the child is active or not along with start/end dates for point in time reporting.

The app/database is primarily a data entry style app. But there's not really anything else (other than the entire row's data  that makes it unique .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a trigger like this if you only need one line at a time. The error handling is suspect, but it gets the point across. If you needed to insert multiple rows you can rewrite the trigger to do the same thing but with many rows

```
CREATE TABLE testaudit(aid INT IDENTITY(1,1),s varchar(10))

CREATE TABLE testauditdetail(aid INT, said INT, s varchar(10),PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(aid, said))


GO 
CREATE TRIGGER reincrementer ON testauditdetail
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    --write it diferently if you plan to insert many rows at once, use error as reminder
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM Inserted) > 1
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (15600,15,1, 'testauditdetail needs one row at a time'); --should use Throw
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        --get inserted stuff to insert for real
        DECLARE @aid INT,@said INT, @s VARCHAR(10)
        SELECT @aid=aid,@s=s FROM Inserted
        --do a FK test to make sure it is cool
        IF (SELECT aid FROM testaudit WHERE aid = @aid) IS NULL 
            BEGIN 
                RAISERROR (15600,15,1, 'bad fk'); --should use Throw or setup your fks to do this
            END 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @said=MAX(said)+1 FROM testauditdetail WHERE aid = @aid
            IF @said IS NULL SET @said = 1
            INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(@aid,@said,@s)
        END 
    END
END
GO
```

Then test it like this

```
INSERT INTO testaudit (s) VALUES('audit a')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(1,0,'a det 1')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(1,0,'a det 2')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(1,0,'a det 3')

INSERT INTO testaudit (s) VALUES('audit b')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(2,0,'a det 1')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(2,0,'a det 2')


INSERT INTO testaudit (s) VALUES('audit c')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(3,0,'a det 1')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(3,0,'a det 2')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(3,0,'a det 3')



INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(3,0,'more det')
INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(3,0,'more det')

SELECT * FROM testaudit
SELECT * FROM testauditdetail
```

Test the fk error like this

```
--bad one to show fk error
--INSERT INTO testauditdetail (aid, said, s) VALUES(4,0,'bad fk')

SELECT * FROM testaudit
SELECT * FROM testauditdetail
```

Comment: Thank You for this. I'm kind of hoping to avoid a trigger, as I've found they can cause more problems than they're worth. Not to mention can be a PITA to debug.


I might have the front end developer handle the logic for the sequence/resetting and take it off the back end. I need to think about that a bit.